# preventing form auto submit ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

I have fetched the data from `database` using `ajax` and i am  showing it to the user using javascript `confirm` dialog. But even after user selects `cancel` option, `form` is being submitted, but I want to submit a form only when user wants to proceed further by selecting `OK` in confirm box. Here is my `code`

```
     <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="post" id="ncell" action="formaction">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

             <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Amount</label>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                         <select class="form-control mb-md" name="amount" id="amount">
                                 <option value="10">10</option>
                                 <option value="20">20</option>
                                 <option value="30">30</option>
                                 <option value="40">40</option>
                                 <option value="50">50</option>
                          </select>

                  </div>
               </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-md">                  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="sub">Submit</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

and my `javascript`

```
<script>
    $("#ncell").submit(function(e){
        var selectedVal= $("select option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "/getdollarvalue",//put y
            data:{ value:selectedVal},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "Json",
            success: function(result){
                return confirm(result.nrs); // Note Send the Json Object from the server side
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

I am now getting the confirm dialog when user clicks the `submit` button. I just want to proceed further only when user clicks `OK` in `confirm` dialog.

Comment: add `preventDefault()` on button click like `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: You need to bind a click event to the ok button to submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
        $("#ncell").submit(function(e){
            var selectedVal= $("select option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "/getdollarvalue",//put y
                data:{ value:selectedVal},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function(result){
                    if(confirm(result.nrs)){
                         $("#ncell").submit();
                  } 
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

or you can use `e.preventDefault();` in place of `return false`.

Comment: I have tried using `return false` and adding `preventdefault`, adding these prevents the form to get submit even in i click `OK` in confirmation dialog.

Comment: You want to submit this form when user click on ok in confirm box?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the button type of your button from submit to button like

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="sub"/>
```

to avoid automatic submit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form when the user presses the ok button, you will need to bind a click event to the ok button to submit the form. 
See example below.

```
$('.ok-btn').click(function(){
    var data = $('form').serialize();
     // your ajax to submit the form and handle the response.
    $.ajax({

    })
});
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put ajax call in function and call it from confirm dialog function
also you should add return false on submit click to prevent the default form submit action:

```js
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
              confirmFunction('Are you sure you want to...');
              return false;
            }

            function confirmFunction(message) {
              //show confirm dialog ( ok - cancel )
              $('#confirm').show();
              $('#confirm p').innerHTML(message);
              $('.ok').on('click', function(){
                ajaxSubmit();
                $('#confirm').hide();
              });
              $('.cancel').on('click', function(){
                $('#confirm').hide();
              });
            }

            function ajaxSubmit() {
              var selectedVal = $("select option:selected").val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/getdollarvalue", //put y
                data: {
                  value: selectedVal
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "Json",
                success: function(result) {
                  return confirm(result.nrs);
                }

              });
            };
```